# Does the “Windows Live” email reader on windows 7 work with Outlook.com

Tags: windows-7, email, windows-live-mail

My mother in law uses the “Windows Live” email reader on her windows 7 laptop, but as she is changing ISPs we need to setup a new email account for her.    Rather than setting the account up with her new ISP we are thinking we should use a free email provider so that she never has to update everyone with her new email address again.

(We both use gmail, but I think Outlook.com will have a more understandable concept of folders for her and work better with a off-line reader.)

I would rather not have to teach her how to use a new UI, hence wishing to keep her on Windows Live Mail.

Also can the mail message be left on Outlook.com and kept in sync so as to provide a level of backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Outlook.com accounts with Windows Live Mail.

The protocol used by Windows Live Mail and Outlook.com means that they are kept synchronised. Any change made in the local client or using web mail will be reflected in the other. There is a feature [to recover deleted emails](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/outlook/recover-deleted-messages) even after the deleted items folder has been cleared.

Comment: Once logged onto Outlook.com the "help" link has instructions on how to set it up - it worked first time when I set it up.